# Rewrite Rule Url To Lowercase Except for Querystring

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, url-rewriting

I have the basic rewrite rule for my web.config file that transforms my urls to lowercase.

Perfect except for one issue: I pass tokens that are case sensitive in my emails that allow users to change their username/emails

How can I make a rewrite rule that makes my url lowercase while having the querystring remain case sensitive?

Example:

```
<rule name="Convert to lower case" stopProcessing="true">  
  <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />  
  <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />  
</rule>
```

Makes this Url:
http://resources.championscentre.org/ConfirmChangeEmail/abcDEfGhIJKlmn

Into This:
http://resources.championscentre.org/confirmchangeemail/abcdefghijklmn

But needs to be:
http://resources.championscentre.org/confirmchangeemail/abcDEfGhIJKlmn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression should be

```
^[\w:\/\.]*\/
```

`\w is [a-zA-Z0-9]`

`^` anchors the begining.

`^[\w:\/\.]*` mathes any alpha number or `/` or `:` or `.`

`/` at the end ensures that the last `/` is selected. (assuming that your URL doesnt ends with /)

[check the example](http://regex101.com/r/gT0uR3/1)

```
<rule name="Convert to lower case" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*[A-Z].*)(\/.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:1}}{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

Comment: I just added your regular expression into my <match url="^[\w:\/\.]*\/" ignoreCase="false" /> and it broke the entire sites appearance. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Mickey am not sure of the syntax . havn't used asp.net. But the regex works fine.

Comment: Ok... I added the expression to IIS and it's working. Thank you... But its not doing exactly what I need. It doesn't make anything after .org lowercase. I need everything lowercase except a querystring. https://resources.championscentre.org/ChangeEmail/?id=ABCdef needs to be https://resources.championscentre.org/changeemail/?id=ABCdef

Comment: In asp.net the last param in the route would be the querystring. http://resources.championscentre.org/changeemail/IAMAQUERYSTRING

Comment: what output are you getting??...matches fine for me check this [link](http://regex101.com/r/gT0uR3/2)

Comment: Example: Goto: https://resources.championscentre.org/Browse/Podcast This should at least be https://resources.championscentre.org/browse/podcast Sorry if Im making things more complicated. I don't know anything about regex and iis rewritre rules

Comment: but according to your defenition resources.championscentre.org/changeemail/IAMAQUERYSTRING

in  resources.championscentre.org/Browse/Podcast , Podcast is the querry string??

Comment: Yes... so in that example, ChangeEmail isnt being lowercased, but i need it to be. So only when the last param is a querystring and not part of the routing (folder)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62947/discussion-between-nu11p01n73r-and-mickey).